# Unable to display Product with its description in home page of rwd theme?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, product-list, rwd-theme, home

I am trying to display a product with its description on the home page

It only allows to display price and name?

How to display some description with it?

I use `{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="5" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}` in `cms-> homepage`. Which display only product name and price.

I need to display description of product with it.

Comment: Please share your code that you using to achive this, so I can help you better

Comment: you can manage with product collection, If you can do that and don't get success then please share your product collection code here.

Answer (score 0):

From the RWD file in app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml line 105:

```
<div class="desc std">
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product,$_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
 <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
</div>
```

Try changing to `echo $_product->getDescription()` or edit other parts in `catalog/product/list.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

The general issue is, that collection used from product listing does not load the same amount of attributes as `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);` normally would.

To add additional attribute to product list collection, go to administration:

> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes

Find attribute you are interested in and set it to 'Used in Product Listing' = Yes.

With this change you can get the attribute value as you would expect in your list.phtml template:

```
<?php echo $product->getDescription() ?>
```

However this will add the attribute to all product list collections, if you are interested in a single product on homepage, custom block solution would be definitely better.

Comment: Its working perfectly now........Thank you...